# No audio output from Banshee

Tags: sound, lubuntu, lenovo, music, banshee

I installed Banshee player on my old Lenovo G430 running Lubuntu 15.04 (Vivid). It was able to scan through my music library and add all files to the library. However, when I try playing something, it goes through all the motions: the play time progresses, and the seek bar moves.. but it does not output any audio.

Audio and video play back fine in other applications, it's just Banshee that doesn't output anything. I couldn't see any options in the preferences to choose an output device, so I assume it plays back to the default output. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Install the Pulseaudio tool `pavucontrol` and open it up. Find the Banshee playback. When it plays, is there an output Pulse notices? Confirm it's not muted and everything. If you can't solve the problem, run Banshee from the terminal and look for any messages that might log playback difficulties.

Comment: Thanks! I installed `pavucontrol`, and audio started working immediately! Maybe it was a problem of a missing dependency that was installed with this package.
Logs here: http://pastebin.com/QnaUgACz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fit this into an answer:

It was reported that my comment to → **install `pavucontrol`** ← worked with only that first step taken. Maybe some wrong configuration residues. Nice.

Comment: I was having this problem (Banshee stopped playing sound only today, everything else worked), and `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` fixed it immediately. Weeeeeeeird!

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me a second time. Since I had already installed `pavucontrol`, I opened it up and under the `Playback` tab, I found that the application I was having trouble with was indeed playing sound, but had the wrong output selected (HDMI instead of Analog Stereo, in my case.)

I switched output from the dropdown menu, and that fixed the problem.