# No audio in gmusicbrowser, guayadeque, banshee etc but VLC OK

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, music, gstreamer

first post here, new to Linux/Ubuntu (14.04).

I had Gmusicbrowser, Guayadeque all working then I decided to install Banshee through software center to have a look.

Something went wrong during the installation (I cant remember exactly what but it stopped). I seem to remember something about having to remove another package (a library?) in order for Banshee to install. Anyway it all got a bit messy.

When I had finally managed to install Banshee there was no sound, although it appeared to be playing.

Then I checked Rythymbox, Gmusicbrowser and Guayadeque and the same problem - playing but no sound.

VLC works fine.
Test sounds in Settings works fine

I guess this means that gstreamer is the problem?
I cant seem to find out exactly what parts/pluggins/etc of gstreamer are needed for these music players to work, or how to 'clean reinstall gstreamer and these parts/pluggins/etc.

I have looked through forums and tried various things (e.g. see below) but am going round in circles

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get remove --purge banshee

sudo apt-get install banshee

sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo alsa force-reload
```

etc etc...

Any help most gratefully received!

EDIT: Well, the 'related' posts to the right had  [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662402/no-audio-output-from-banshee?rq=1) which led me via pavucontrol to find that the unplugged HDMI was selected for Guayadeque and Gmusicbrowser and changing it to built-in audio solved the problem.

How do I set this as default?

ALso, should I now start a new post? (since I also have the problem that the internal and usb mikes are incorrectly labeld in pavucontrol (i.e. if I select unplugged USB the internal registers)